# Error: Cannot access file bin/Debug/... because it is being used by another process

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, projects-and-solutions, locked-files

When I debug my project, I get following error:

> "Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\My Dream.exe" to "bin\Debug\My Dream.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\My Dream.exe' because it is being used by another process."

Using Process Explorer, I see that MyApplication.exe was out but System process still uses it although I stopped debug before.
Whenever I change my code and start debug it is going to happen. If I copy project to USB and debug, it runs OK.

Why? How can I fix this error?

I use Window 7 Professional. With Xp I have never got this error.

Comment: win7 sometimes keeps locks on files that are being viewed in explorer, so make sure you don't have your debug folder open.

Comment: I think System process using it.

Comment: It's either a lock, or some idiot added /bin to source control, and now the files are write-protected (right click on bin, uncheck write-protected).

Comment: As one of the answers is tagged as Solution, I cannot add more answers but a comment. In my case, I solved the issue by removing the relf recurring reference from the .cporj file, by getting the tip from the following topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301625/visual-studio-could-not-write-to-output-file-obj-debug-foo-bar-dll

Comment: This is worse in Visual Studio 2017 than its ever been before.

Comment: In my case `MSBuild.exe` had a hold on the file, simply end the process in Task Manager

Comment: VS2019 and still happening

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Ugh, this is an old problem, something that still pops up in Visual Studio once in a while. It's bitten me a couple of times and I've lost hours restarting and fighting with VS. I'm sure it's been discussed here on SO more than once. It's also been talked about on the MSDN forums. There isn't an actual solution, but there are a couple of workarounds. [Start researching here](http://www.google.com/search?&q=debug+being+used+by+another+process+visual+studio).

What's happening is that VS is acquiring a lock on a file and then not releasing it. Ironically, that lock prevents VS itself from deleting the file so that it can recreate it when you rebuild the application. The only apparent **solution is to close and restart VS** so that it will release the lock on the file.

My original workaround was opening up the bin/Debug folder and renaming the executable. You can't *delete* it if it's locked, but you can rename it. So you can just add a number to the end or something, which allows you to keep working without having to close all of your windows and wait for VS to restart. [Some people have even automated this using a pre-build event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19649014/366904) to append a random string to the end of the old output filename. Yes, this is a *giant* hack, but this problem gets so frustrating and debilitating that you'll do anything.

I've later learned, after a bit more experimentation, that the problem seems to only crop up when you build the project with one of the designers open. So, the solution that has worked for me long term and prevented me from ever dealing with one of those silly errors again is making sure that I always close all designer windows before building a WinForms project. Yes, this too is somewhat inconvenient, but it sure beats the pants off having to restart VS twice an hour or more.

I assume this applies to WPF, too, although I don't use it and haven't personally experienced the problem there.

I also haven't yet tried reproducing it on VS 2012 RC. I don't know if it's been fixed there yet or not. But my experience so far has been that it still manages to pop up even after Microsoft has claimed to have fixed it. It's still there in VS 2010 SP1. I'm not saying their programmers are idiots who don't know what they're doing, of course. I figure there are just multiple causes for the bug and/or that it's very difficult to reproduce reliably in a laboratory. That's the same reason I haven't personally filed any bug reports on it (although I've +1'ed other peoples), because I can't seem to reliably reproduce it, rather like the Abominable Snowman.

<sub><end rant that is directed at no one in particular></sub>

Comment: I understand your solution but you can explain why it did not happen when i build it on XP or on an USB.Is it related to user 's permission on Window 7? Of course,i am the aministrator now.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I wanted to leave a comment to anyone who finds this, that closing the designer files also fixed my issue on an ASP.NET WebForms solution in VS2012 Update 3.

Comment: This is still happening (for me) in VS2013. It's always the PDB file for the WPF project in my solution that gets locked in the target directory. Closing all designers didn't work (boo!) but renaming the file did (thanks, Cody!). Giant hack beckons...

Comment: This started to happen to me since yesterday when i upgraded to vS 2013... this hadn't happened to me once since VS 2008... so sad.

Comment: I realize this post is a bit old but I ran across the same problem and what I found is that if my selected build configuration doesn't match my selected publish configuration this happens.  That is to say...let's say I have Debug selected as my build config but my publish is pointing to a config that is release, one of the projects will exhibit this issue.

Comment: closing the designer files didn't fix my issue

Comment: VS 2015, and I still have the issue.

Comment: Although this is marked as the correct answer, and people are still posting comments that it's not fixing them, take a look at the next answer below.  It's been working for me for a while, even across VS versions.

Comment: @ScottN Your solution does exactly what my answer suggests: *"Some people have even automated this using a pre-build event to append a random string to the end of the old output filename. Yes, this is a giant hack, but this problem gets so frustrating and debilitating that you'll do anything."* :-)

Comment: @CodyGray gotcha :-)  Definitely a very frustrating VS issue.

Comment: sorry, have to vent, Microsoft sucks sometimes.

Comment: Good god thank you for this solution. Never experienced this before. What a PITA.

Comment: It's happening in Visual Studio 17, and restarting Visual Studio doesn't help.

Comment: Indeed! It was the designer. I am now using VS 2013 and I was facing this silly bug since VS 2005. Thank you so much.

Comment: You can't rename it if its locked

Comment: @jairhumberto Incorrect.  See my answer below which has been working for years to rename locked files. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19649014/27494

Comment: @ScottN I tested it, that's why I said that's not possible. The Windows says: you can't rename it since the file is blocked, however since you know more than the Windows, you could tell them and teach them a little, because this error is really a pain in the ass. And the Windows, doesn't allow you to rename a blocked file.

Comment: @jairhumberto no reason for the snark, computers are frustrating enough as it is, no need to pass that on to someone else.. but this works for me for this specific issue, maybe you're having something different!  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19649014/27494

Comment: Happened to me with VS 2019 today, open/closing VS did not work but renaming the exe worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I get the same problem in VS 2019 when running ASP NET Core. There is a single exe file called `nameofproject.exe` inside `bin\Debug\net5.0` and I can't delete or rename it.

Answer (score 66):

I've had this error crop up on me before, even in Visual Studio 2008.  It came back and more prevalent in Visual Studio 2012.

Here is what I do.

Paste this in the troublesome project's pre-build event:

```
if exist "$(TargetPath).locked" del "$(TargetPath).locked"
if exist "$(TargetPath)" if not exist "$(TargetPath).locked" move "$(TargetPath)" "$(TargetPath).locked"
```

Comment: Where I can find that `Pre-Build` event on my windows form??

Comment: @qwerty It's found in the project's properties under the Build Events section or if you're on VB.net project, under Compile section, you'll see a Build Events button.

Comment: @ScottN: oh BTW, this `pre-build` code is also the remedy for deployed(via a clickonce) application when my app is running then a bug/glitch occurred then on the task manager, I will end task my `myApp.exe` but will not END TASK and it prompt `ERROR ON ENDING TASK` ?

Comment: @qwerty No, this has no association with a ClickOnce deployed application.  This error is only when you're building your application during development and testing and only in Visual Studio, not for any deployed application running on client systems.

Comment: What does `.locked` refer to?

Comment: It's just the file extension used that is different than the target, so to free up the target filename for building.  The extension could be whatever you want, but `.locked` is a descriptive file extension just for this purpose.

Comment: I updated the pre-build to perform the same with the pdb file, but I'm still getting this error: `CS2012 Cannot open 'C:\Users\<trimmed>UWP\obj\x86\Debug\Proj.UWP.pdb' for writing -- 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\<trimmed>.UWP.pdb' because it is being used by another process.' Proj.UWP C:\Users\weitz\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Proj\Proj\Proj.UWP\CSC`

Comment: What does your pre-build look like now?  I've never seen the `.pdb` file have issues with this, so your problem might not be related specifically to this Visual Studio issue.  Have you tried restarting Visual Studio and make sure all instances of your app are terminated?  Last resort, reboot the entire machine?

Answer (score 23):

Computer (right-click) -> manage -> Service & Application -> service -> Enable Application experience

Worked For me!

Comment: I had disabled this service a few months ago. Enabling it now seemed to solve the problem in Visual Studio (unable to copy due to the exe file being locked). I wonder why this service needs to be running, what I read about it did not seem related to anything relevant for this error (eg. http://www.blackviper.com/windows-services/application-experience/).

Comment: I have this service running but still get the lock issue.

Comment: +1 Wow, I tried /everything/ else I found.  Finally stumbled on this to fix it.  Mine was disabled as well.  Would have never thought that as the culprit!

Comment: Running Windows 7 SP1 with VS2010 SP1, turnning on "Application Experience" services immediately help me out. Thanks a lot. But one minute later turning it off does not reproduce the problem immediately.

Comment: service not found in windows 10

Comment: @JerryGoyal, it seems to be a scheduled task in Windows 10 under Microsoft → Windows → Application Experience. Disabling this did not work for me on Windows 10, but it does on Windows 7.

Comment: This is so interesting. This solution is worked for me too. I wonder that what is purpose of this service?

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue in Visual Studio 2013.  I'm not sure what caused this for my project, but I was able to fix it by cleaning the solution and rebuilding it.

1. Build > Clean Solution
2. Build > Rebuild Solution

Comment: Don't try it on large projects... Full rebuild takes really long.

Answer (score 9):

I understand this is an old question. Unfortunately I was facing the same issue with my `.net core 2.0` application in `visual studio 2017`. So, I thought of sharing the solution which worked for me. Before this solution I had tried the below steps.

1. Restarted visual studio
2. Closed all the application
3. Clean my solution and rebuild

None of the above steps didn't fix the issue.

And then I opened my `Task Manager` and selected `dotnet` process and then clicked End task button. Later I opened my Visual Studio and everything was working fine.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

At least in my case I've noticed that visual studio 2012 was creating at least two msbuild.exe ghost processes, which did not perish after build. These zombies apparently are causing file locks to appear.

Killing msbuild.exe's is one time solution, it needs to be done per build basis.

But then I've figure out that I could disable parallel build once and for all - went into Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > "maximum numbers of parallel project builds" - by default it has value of 8, I've switched to 1. Works like charm.

Of course builds are bit slower now, but better safe than sorry.
At least for this particular small project I did not need more than one build thread.

Answer (score 2):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29987762/973624) if you're having this problem while running unit tests. Answer copied below:

> Building upon Sébastien's answer, I added a pre-build step to my test
>   project to automatically kill any `vstest.*` executables still
>   running. The following pre-build command worked for me:
>
> ```
> taskkill /f /im vstest.*
> exit 0
> ```
>
> The `exit 0` command is at the end to prevent build failure when there
>   are no `vstest.*` executables running.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem..

near the debug you see drop down menu with some configuration. Default there was Any CPU. Select x86 and run the program it will work. If x86 not there go to configuration manager and add the x86

Comment: Worked for me with VS2019!

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've been in a trouble with Visual Studio 2012 with same error description: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process..."

To fix this first of all you need to understand the application which still use it. I've shutdown all processes like "MSBuild" and "MSBuild host". But this is not enough. If you have installed "Code Contracts" and turned on then it sometimes takes your DLLs for checking and hanging up on this operation.

So, you need to stop all processes of "CCCheck.exe" and that's all.

Finally, to understand that process is using your DLL you always may try to just Delete "obj" folder in your File Manager and this operation will fail, you may see the "Message Window" with description of the hanging operation. Also, as a variant, you can try to use "Sys Internals Suite" application.

Comment: At least in my case I've noticed that visual studio was creating msbuild.exe ghost processes, which did not perish after build. These zombies apparently are causing file locks to appear. But no clue how to solve it.
Killing msbuild.exe's is one time solution, it needs to be done per build basis.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me. 
Task Manager -> Name of project -> End task. (i had 3 same processes with my project name);

VS 2013; Win 8;

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that any previous run of the application (for example, start without debugging option) is actually stopped. I was working on a WPF application, started without debugging and had it minimized when I kept getting the error. After closing the application VS behavior got back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

I have been plagued by this issue in Visual Studio 2017. It started about two or three weeks ago, and has severely eaten into my productivity. Clean and Rebulid haven't worked; even restarting my machine doesn't do the job.

One way to deal with the issue is to clean the offending assembly, and to build (as opposed to rebuild) the project you want to run immediately afterwards. This works about 30% of the time.

However, probably the most reliable solution I've found is to open a Developer Command Prompt, and use `msbuild` directly. I've been doing this for the last three days, and so far the problem hasn't happened once.

Answer (score 1):

In my case was that I have enable "Show All Files".
Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 1):

Run `taskmanager`.
Locate `netcore` and delete it.
You can then delete the file manually or by running `Clean`.

Answer (score 0):

This is pure speculation, and not an answer.

However, I have been having this problem for a while.

I came after a time to suspect an interaction between VS and my AV precautions.

After some playing, it seems that it **may** have gone away when I modified my antivirus so that everything under the

**C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ProjectAssemblies**

folder was not included in the real-time protection.

It looks as if the build actually writes the DLL here first, then copies it to the final build location.

Answer (score 0):

It could be too late. But, I encountered similar problem and in my case the project had self reference. Hence, deleting it from the References worked like a charm!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the quickest way without closing forms or restarting VisualStudio is go to the project's compile page and click "Advanced Compile Options..." button. Then make any change to one of the options (say, changing Generate Debug Info from Full to pdb-only), then click OK.
It works every time and will have to do until MS fixes this bug (I've never had this problem until I switched from VS2012 to VS2013)

Another note, if you can't clean the project or solution, it won't build. The files are definitely locked by VS (not a antivirus problem, at least not in my case)

Answer (score 0):

I tried all these suggestions as well as other suggestions found elsewhere and the only thing that worked for me was restarting my computer. Then I did a clean solution followed by rebuilding. I am using Visual Studio 2013 for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have run to this same issue, and what I found is there are **actually running mulitple Windows form application** in the background. It happens when your application has two forms and you close the **2nd form** which is not your **main form** so the application will not totally exited.

**I usually run my application**

- through its exe or
- run without debugging

**Solution is close the other instance of Windows form application**.
This is [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10769349/3969838) way to always close your application instance.

Answer (score 0):

Pre build command

```
(if exist "$(TargetDir)*old.pdb" del "$(TargetDir)*old.pdb") & (if exist "$(TargetDir)*.pdb" ren "$(TargetDir)*.pdb" *.old.pdb)
```

Helped

Answer (score 0):

**[Solved] Error: Cannot access file bin/Debug/… because it is being used by another process:**

I am approaching that you get this error while you was trying to run two windows form one after another such as first loading a form then after sometimes it will automatically disappear and the second form loaded onto the screen.

Basically, you need to close your first form which is running in the background and the main reason behind this error.

To close the first form you have to add these two lines of code in the second form load event handler.

```
    Form1 form = new Form1();
    form.Close();
```

This will solve the error perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is you go to bin\Debug folder, delete all the files in that folder, then rebuild. If it doesn't work, close Visual Studio then go to bin\Debug folder using file explorer, on the left coner, click on File> Open Command Prompt> Open Command Prompt as Administrator > Enter this command "DEL /F /Q /A *" > then rebuild

Answer (score 0):

i found Cody Gray 's answer partially helpful, in that it did direct me to the real source of my problem which some of you may also be experiencing: visual studio's test execution stays open by default and maintains a lock on the files.

To stop that predominantly useless behaviour, follow the instructions from https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/771994/vstest-executionengine-x86-exe-32-bit-not-closing-vs2012-11-0-50727-1-rtmrel

Uncheck Test menu -> Test Settings -> "Keep Test Execution Engine Running"

Answer (score 0):

My problem was dotnet got hung up and whenever VS would try to make a new dll, or access an old one, the dotnet process would latch onto the dll and stop visual studio from cloning the dll. Solution is just to end all dotnet tasks in task manager(it will only actually remove the dead one, if you are trying to end one and it won't shut down, that means it's working).

Answer (score 0):

Close VisualStudio, ctrl-alt-delete, select Task Manager, find and end all MSBuild processes - VisualStudio basically has a pretty severe bug where it loses control of its debugger and the debugger maintains a lock on the .pdb file in the debug/bin folder.  After you end all the MSBuild (debugger) processes, delete the /debug/bin folder and reopen your solution in Visual Studio.  You're good to go now.  Microsoft needs to fix this crap.

Answer (score 0):

I have opened a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49364962/visual-studio-is-locking-the-executable-which-needs-to-be-built/49452278#49452278) regarding VS 2017 that had a similar behavior after one update. The problem seemed to be generated by the antivirus program although.

*I have added the bin folder to the antivirus exclude list, restarted the machine and now it seems to work.*

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue, but none of the answers above helped me! I just simply closed my Visual Studio 2017 then re-run it, and It worked!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried every answered here and this worked for me

1. Close your Project.
2. Stop running tasks in task manager
3. Restart your pc
4. Open and build project again

it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I was running my solution, but not in debug mode. I had forgotten this. I realized it and stopped my solution from running. This cleared up the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your application/program is probably running in Console. Kill it by closing the console, then rebuild/publish and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution Could be:

(if in “Release” to “Debug” and vice versa), build and then change back to previous configuration and build again.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Another kludge, ugh, but it's easy and works for me in VS 2013.  Click on the project.  In the properties panel should be an entry named Project File with a value

(your project name).vbproj

Change the project name - such as adding an -01 to the end.  The original .zip file that was locked is still there, but no longer referenced ... so your work can continue.  Next time the computer is rebooted, that lock disappears and you can delete the errant file.