# Visual Studio 2012 err "could not write to output file '....some.dll'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis-express

When debugging my MVC4 app, using local IIS Express in Visual Studio 2012, each time I get

```
Description:
Could not write to output file '...\obj\Debug\some...dll'
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

File: CSC
```

I always have to close/kill IIS from the system-tray - then it builds and runs.

This is soo anoying - is there a good solution for this problem?

I looked at http://www.csharp411.com/run-asp-net-and-iis-on-windows-vista-and-7-home-premium/ which refers to IIS and inetmgr.exe - which I cannot find for IIS-Express!

thank you!

Comment: No one else having this problem???

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can't open files for writing that are already open for reading somewhere else (unless specifically allowed by the programme that opened the file previously - which the kernel won't do for files that are being run). You can, however, rename files that are in use, so you could add the following as a pre-build event in MSVC:

```
ren ...\obj\Debug\some...dll ...\obj\Debug\some...dll.bak
```

Substitute paths as appropriate. Not sure if your IIS is gonna pick that up though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the same issue but possibly related to this question:
[Visual Studio Could not write to output file '...\obj\Debug\Foo.Bar.dll"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301625/visual-studio-2010-could-not-write-to-output-file-obj-debug-foo-bar-dll)