# Why is referenced dll getting locked while debugging under Resharper/MSTest?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, debugging, resharper, mstest

I have an integration test for a method in assembly `A`. Assembly `A` references assembly `B` via project reference. I run them under the Visual Studio 2010 debugger in a Resharper 6.1 unit testing scenario. The testing engine is Microsoft's native MSTest.

I get the infamous

> The process cannot access the file `...\B.dll` because it is being used by another process.

message. I have verified that no other process has a handle on that file (e.g. via Sysinternal's Process Explorer).

Running the test out of the debugger works fine. Any ideas why it happens under the debugger and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Do you have any build events for project B? Is your test doing anything specific with B?

Comment: Nothing special. The test project `A` worked fine before the `B` project reference, which is set to copy local btw.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have seen a similar situation, and found in the task manager that vtest.discoveryengine.exe and vtest.executionengine.exe were still alive. I killed both, which solved the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Building upon Sébastien's answer, I added a pre-build step to my test project to automatically kill any `vstest.*` executables still running. The following pre-build command worked for me:

```
taskkill /f /im vstest.*
exit 0
```

The `exit 0` command is at the end to prevent build failure when there are no `vstest.*` executables running.

Comment: This was the quickest, most effective workaround for me.

Comment: Err. I don't understand pre-build events. I copypasted what you have here and I get errors: `The command "taskkill /f /im vstest.*
exit 0" exited with code -1.`

Comment: You need to put `exit 0` on another line; *taskkill* is thinking you are using `exit` as an argument.

Comment: @Kit Yeah, this doesn't work for me :( My comment wasn't clear - with these two lines, if the process doesn't exist, I get an error building: `the process vstest.* was not found.`

Comment: @mrtumnus I used the answer here instead of exit 0 as that didn't work for me: http://superuser.com/a/433002/167358 - although it has to start a command window, it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Building upon @mrtumnus' answer and [the answer here](https://superuser.com/a/433002/167358), I added a pre-build step to my test project to automatically kill any `vstest.*` executables:

```
START taskkill /f /im vstest.*
```

Using `START` instead of `exit 0` so it doesn't give an error if the task isn't running. (It does open a command window, though, which is a bit annoying).

Comment: with vs 2023 + resharper 2023 I experienced a similar problem that could be fixed with: (START /wait taskkill /f /im ReSharperTestRunner64.exe) & EXIT 0