# Visual Studio debugging - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I keep getting this error the first time I try to run my program (debug mode) from inside Visual Studio 2015.

[image]

So what happens is I'll hit the Start button to start debugging, and it gives this error.  I close the dialog, then try it again and it works.  It happens every time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Close VS and reopen it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Cannot access file bin/Debug/... because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646047/error-cannot-access-file-bin-debug-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-proc)

Comment: This can happen when you have 2 Visual Studios open (1 running), referencing the same project or dll - or when for instance you have a console app running of the project independently which locks the dll.

Comment: A question like this needs to document the installed anti-malware product.  The crappy ones don't deal that well with an EXE file that seemingly came from nowhere.  They won't let you start it until their "deep scan" is complete.