# Visual Studio is locking the executable which needs to be built

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to run the application on which I am working and from time to time Visual Studio is not able to build the project only because it is locking the executable:

[image]

This started to happen after the last update of Visual Studio and it does not happen every build but just from time to time. Closing and reopening the solution removes the error temporary but after a few more builds it comes back.

I am trying to build a solution containing more DLLs and one WPF project and the error seems to be on the WPF one.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem in VS 2017?

Comment: That was an old problem I have no more witnessed by a lot of time. There is a question with many answers that could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646047/error-cannot-access-file-bin-debug-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-proc

Comment: VS does not lock executable files, your installed anti-malware product does.  It injects itself into processes to do its dirty deeds.  The crapware always gets its underwear in a bundle when it sees an executable file appear from nowhere.  MSBuild has a workaround for it, but when the "deep scan" takes its usual merry time then it does give up.  Life is too short to deal with that, favor the one included with your OS.

Comment: @Steve, I have seen that question and it is interesting that it appeared again after so much time. I faced it in some old VS 2010 projects, but now I don't know what it made it come back, except the fact that I have installed the latest VS updates. I may close this question as a duplicate eventually.

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant for your reply! It is strange that the problem seems to appear after the latest VS update. Also it is specified in the description of the error that the file is locked by Microsoft Visual Studio so I do not know what to say. The machine has the same antivirus installed for a couple of years but this never happened before (except on the VS 2010 a while ago).

Comment: Antivirus could really be a problem. I have almost forgot that bit. I keep every project/solution in a subfolder and told the antivirus to mind its business elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the *bin* folder to the antivirus *exclude list*, restarted the machine and now it seems to work. For a couple of days Visual Studio is not locking anymore the executable so as @Hans Passant pointed in his comment, it may not be a Visual Studio problem.